# Open Folder just created by batch script from user input

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to modify my script so that when the user enters the required information for what the folder should be called, it opens that created folder. However, when trying to use the start function it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I also need to make my code accept special characters such as / & * etc when naming a folder. But this keeps returning an error and won't create the folder.

EDIT: Here is my code

```
echo "Please Name Folder"
SET /p template= 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
md C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%\Pictures
md C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%\Videos

:choice
SET /p c=Does the Folder Contain Videos[Y/N/]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :Videos
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :Pictures
goto :choice

:Videos
echo "Please Add Folder Name"
SET /p SubFolder=
md C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%\Videos\%SubFolder%
start C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%
pause
exit

:Pictures
echo "Please Add Folder Name"
SET /p SubFolder=
md C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%\Pictures\%SubFolder%
start C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%
pause
exit
```

Comment: show your code, so we can tell you where and why it fails.

Comment: Added the code as requested

Comment: Quote your paths to correctly use special characters like SPACE and `&`. Some other special characters like `/` and `*` are not allowed in folder- or file-names. `md "C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%\Pictures\%SubFolder%"` and `start "" "C:\Users\Obi\Desktop\%template%"` (see `start /?` for why the additional `""``)